# My Settings Link disappears sometimes

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

In the Top right Context Menu from SharePoint 2010 there exists a link "My Settings".

[image]

Does anyone know why this link disappears to some users?

They all use IE version 8.0 not Chrome or firefox or s.th.

There are no custom scripts that can take this effect or s.th.

Comment: Don't have a SP2010 environment to test, but could the link be there only on certain context? For example it wouldn't be there while navigating on folders or certain type of pages?

Comment: I think that it is not set to a specific context. Because other users see this link in the same context. :(